# jQuery clone elements with-in a main wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a summary page where I grab all content form the main page and show it in a overlapping div sort of like images are displayed these days.

Now problem that I get I lose `input` and `select` values once I past it into a summary / print wrap.

**jQuery**

```
    $(".header").clone().appendTo('.page');
    $(".task").clone().appendTo('.page');
    $(".options").clone().appendTo('.page');
```

`.header` and `.task` are just plain text input. And that works just fine. However with in the `.options` I have many controls like `textarea`, `input`, and `select` ... I get all the elements into `.page` however I lose all the selected values and text.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the inputs are not stored in the attribute tag value. This means that the copy will not have the value set. So before you copy them set the value attr.

```
function CopyStuffToPage() {
    // Doing this will change the HTML for all the input elements
    $('input').each(function(index,element) {
       $(element).attr('value',$(element).val());
    });
    $('textarea').each(function(index,element) {
       $(element).html($(element).val());
    });
    $('select').each(function(index,element) {
       var value = $(element).val();
       $(element).children('option').removeAttr('selected');
       $(element).children('option[value='+value+']').attr('selected','selected');
    });

    // Then you can do this
    $(".header").clone().appendTo('.page');
    $(".task").clone().appendTo('.page');
    $(".options").clone().appendTo('.page');
}
```

For selects you will have to add the attribute 'selected' to the option for which the select has selected.

I had this same issue when I wanted to save the contents of a div through PHP I had to set the attribute tags then send the HTML.

Edit: To Clerify the values of the elements you are copying are not stored as

```
<input value='this value'/>
```

they are stored in the DOM thus cloning them only clones the html not the value.

Comment: I am not having any luck with this, possibly I am not understanding the process in your example.

Comment: What you are doing with the code in my example is taking the value out of the elementDomObject and putting it into the HTML of the page. If you view a <input> element and you look inspect it using chrome or whatever you will see that you cannot see the value inside because it is not in the HTML tag, it will be stored in the DOMObject instead.

Comment: This works fine I need to read trough it as I don't understand it at all. So what is the $(element). Is there a tutorial I can look over that explains this..

Comment: turns out this doesn't work after I rerun the function. It comes back all blank.

Comment: Fixed: every element must have a value if its just <option>Select</option> it won't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localstorage` for a quick patch to your problem.
Store the values within the textbox and textarea as,

```
//retrieving value from textbox and text area,
var textbox = $("#id-of-textbox").val();
var textarea = $("#id-of-textarea").val();

//retrieving the selected value for 'select'
var selectedValue = $('#id-of-select').val();

//storing the value in localstorage
localstorage.setItem("textbox", textbox);
localstorage.setItem("textarea", textarea);
localstorage.setItem("select", selectedValue);

//You can retrieve the above stored values anywhere you want as,
var newtextbox = localstorage.getItem("textbox");
var newtextarea = localstorage.getItem("textarea");
var newselect = localstorage.getItem("select");

//It is advisable to remove the store data after it's use,
localstorage.removeItem("textbox");
localstorage.removeItem("textarea");
localstorage.removeItem("select");
```

Advantage of using `localstorage` is that the data is stored within user's browser so you can access it on any page just like session data.

Comment: This won't work because I have rows that have same id's so if I use this it won't know which textbox I am targeting... It can have 1 or many same as select

Comment: @theStudent it seems like you are generating the rows dynamically. To make this solution work you can make every 'id' unique as id = "myId"+count and increment the value of 'count'each time you create a new row.

Comment: True I do have that but still once user completes I still can't use your solution as I won't know how many rows there are. Your solution forks if I have fixed number of elements and i can hard code each element in like this.